# Android ArrayAdapter unpredictably making rows different colors

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView adapter that puts a custom class into a listview.  The custom class is simple, it's a NameValue that simply has two strings (one for the name, the other for the value).  If the name is Key, I want to use one XML layout for the row; if it's anything else, use another XML layout.  Here is the code for my adapter:

```
private class ApInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NameValue> {
    private ArrayList<NameValue> adapterPairs;

    public ApInfoAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<NameValue> pairs) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, pairs);
        this.adapterPairs = pairs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        adapterPair = adapterPairs.get(position);

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (adapterPair.name.equals("Key")) {
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.info_row_key, null); // This makes the key red
            } else {
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.info_row, null); // All others have use the default foreground color 
            }
        }

        if (adapterPair != null) {
            TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView value = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value);
            name.setText(adapterPair.name);
            value.setText(adapterPair.value);

        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes it makes value for the row where the name is "Key" red, but sometimes it makes value on other rows red (sometimes one row, sometimes multiple rows).  When the colors are off, I have noticed that other rows will also be incorrectly colored as I scroll the ListView up and down.  I have also noticed that the problem is worse on my Samsung Galaxy S2 than on my Nexus 7 Razor.  My question for the experts is: what am I doing incorrectly, and how do I fix it?  Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set background manually for the case when `v` is not `null` as it can be any `View`, not only the proper one.